# performance of functional architecture with modules vs. class types, in F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I understand that functional architecture is encouraged in F#, but I'm hitting a performance wall that doesn't exist with class types.

I have a state type with a bunch of fields in it and it is passed around a series of functions through the code pipeline.
At every state, when some transformation occurs, a new object is created.

Some example is this:

```
match ChefHelpers.evaluateOpening t brain with
| Some openOrder ->
    info $"open order received: {openOrder.Side}"
    match! ExchangeBus.submitOneOrderRetryAsync brain.Exchange openOrder with
    | Ok _->
        {brain.CookOrder.Instrument.PriceToString openOrder.Price} / sl.{stopLossOrder.Side.Letter} at {brain.CookOrder.Instrument.PriceToString stopLossOrder.Price}"
        let m = $"{t.Timestamp.Format}: send open order {openOrder.Side}, last price was {brain.CookOrder.Instrument.PriceToString brain.Analysis.LastPrice}"
        return Message m, ({ brain.WithStatus (Cooking MonitorForClose) with OpenOrder = Some openOrder })
    | Error e ->
        let m = $"{t.Timestamp}: couldn't open position:\n{e.Describe()}"
        return! ChefHelpers.cancelAllOrdersAsync brain (ChefError m) (ExchangeError (Other (e.Describe())))
| None ->
    return NoMessage, brain
```

Where the object 'brain' that holds all the states will get passed around, updated, etc

And this works very well when run live since everything may get executed a 2-3 times per second at most.

When I want to run the same code on static data to check behavior, etc, this is a different story because I'm running it millions of times while I'm waiting for it to finish.
All this code is dealing with small lists, doing basic comparisons, arithmetic, etc so the the cost of rebuilding the main object sticks out and becomes painfully apparent.

I tried to rebuild some of that logic as an object type where the state is a bunch of mutable variables and the performance difference is dramatic.

I have a lot of code like this:

```
type A = { }

let a : A = ...

let a = doSomething1 a
let a = doSomething2 a
let a =    
    match x with
    | true -> doSomething3 a
    | false -> a

 etc
```

I'd say the whole tool architecture is built with code that looks like that.

and there is a lot of these:

```
let a = { a with X = 3 }
```

but there is no concurrency in the pipeline and it is very linear, so in the case of the last line, if I had a way to tell the compiler: it's the same object, it is not used anywhere else, edit it in place, then the performance would be a lot better.

What could be strategies I could use to keep the code readable, but minimize that issue?
Is the problem the actual data copying? the main object has 18 fields, so I can't imagine it being larger than 200 bytes, allocating space for it? or does it create a lot of garbage collection?

It's not something straightforward to profile since it's a cost that's everywhere and inside dotnet.

Any feedback / ideas would be great, especially "you're doing it wrong, do X instead" :)

Comment: This question can be closed for any of several reasons. It is opinion-based, it is too broad, it needs more focus, it needs details or clarity, it needs debugging details, there's nothing specific we can reproduce. How can there be any one right answer? Sorry, but that makes it a prime example of a question that doesn't fit the format of SO. I don't mean to be rude or anything like that. It's a good question and good topic for discussion that I'm sure would engage people. How about you post it on F# Slack or one of the other discussion-oriented F# forums instead?

Comment: Maybe the wording is too open since I typed it as I was figuring out the issue. The compiled result of the functional vs oo forms for similar operations is something that would fit on SO. But I agree that currently it’s too open. Maybe we could close it and I’ll reformulate it with some sample code.

Comment: Or you could just edit it I guess. If you also decide to raise the general issue in a forum elsewhere, then it would be nice to have a link or reference here.

Comment: I've been thinking about what might make a good question. I think issues that you can put a label on (metaphorically) might be good points, like immutability and piping. If performance degradation can be demonstrated in relation to these, that might call for useful answers.

Comment: @BentTranberg, when I have time, I will write one question with sample code to demonstrate the performance gap, then we can link this one to it and archive it.

Comment: I have a server that for the most part is one giant state machine, that controls a production line. The core structure of this state machine uses classes, and the lower-level (or leaf-) structures that handles items, bundles and packages ... are records. I am actually considering that even these become classes in the state machine, because of the hassles involved doing things the pure functional way when increasingly more functionality is attached to items, bundles and packages. In F# using classes is not considered a bad thing at all. Traditional OO with inheritance is bad.

Answer (score 1):

From a design perspective, 18 fields is actually a fairly large record, in my opinion. Perhaps you could factor that into sub-records, so you're not constantly re-allocating the entire thing? So instead of this:

```ml
type A =
    {
        X : int
        Field1 : int
        Field2 : int
        ...
        Field18 : int
    }
```

You could have this instead:

```ml
type Sub1 =
    {
        Field1 : int
        ...
        Field9 : int
    }

type Sub2 =
    {
        Field10 : int
        ...
        Field18 : int
    }

type A =
    {
        X : int
        Sub1 : Sub1
        Sub2 : Sub2
    }
```

Then the performance cost of `let a = { a with X = 3 }` would presumably be less.

Bonus idea: You might also want to emulate the cool Haskell kids, and look into [lenses](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/lens.html), which are designed specifically for reading and updating parts of immutable data.